# Windows 7 persistent remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 x64 machine that I remote desktop into. The problem I have is when I log into the machine it loads the desktop fine. Once I close the remote desktop (no official log out.) and then log back in it reloads the desktop. I want it to preserve the session I was working in last time rather than resetting the session.

This is a headless machine so I log in initial and always from a remote machine.

Comment: what do you use for remote desktop?

Comment: I use the Remote desktop that comes with Windows XP Service Pack 3.

Comment: How are you closing the session? Just the X?

Comment: Yes, I just click the X in the upper right hand corner of the window.

Comment: I use Windows7 all the time.  I login to it remotely from an XP SP3 machine and I have NEVER had the problem you describe.  You dont need to worry about "console" session.

Comment: Are you sure that the machine isn't rebooting due to updates or a BSOD? I would check the event log for anything bad funny that is going on behind your back.

Comment: Sorry, I can't leave a comment, or I would.

Have you tried TechPardox's answer? 

I do the same thing. If you don't mind staying logged on, you can use the "Disconnect" from the Start menu. When you connect again via remote Desktop, it will be the same as you left it. I do this all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I use XP's built-in RDP when I need to connect to my Win7 box at home from work.  I've not run into the problem you are describing, but typically when I close an RDP session I use Start > Disconnect instead of clicking the X in the corner of the RDP bar (but either method should disconnect instead of logging you off.)  I'd suggest checking to see if you have more than one open session by using the QWINSTA command and kill any errant sessions using RWINSTA, then try reconnecting and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal services manager tool will expose the 2 (or more) sessions you have connected and you should be able to tell the difference between the multiple sessions and it will you a hint to your problem.   Make sure your external IP address always remains the same from connection to connection, otherwise it might think it needs to make a new session for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something nobody else mentioned: perhaps your Terminal Services configuration on the Windows7 machine is set so that sessions expire after they are inactive for a few minutes?